# How to read Java InputStream without delay?

Tags: java, inputstream, stdout

I have C++ program (feeder.exe), that prints some data:

```
printf("%s\n", line);
```

In average it produces 20-30 lines per second, but not uniformly.

I want to catch this data in Java program by running the exe from Java code:

```
package temp_read;    
import java.io.*;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("d:/feeder.exe");
        InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() + "," + line);
        }
    }
}
```

But when I look into the output, I see that it receives a bulk of strings once per 3-5 seconds.

**Question**: how to receive the data from feeder.exe immediately without any delay when it prints to stdout?

PS: not related question: How to stop the feeder.exe if I stop the java by Ctrl+C?

Comment: Try running `feeder.exe | more` are you are likely to see the same behaviour.  I suspect the buffered is in the pipe, not due to how Java reads it.

Comment: Don't ask unrelated questions in the same Question.  Ask as a different Question.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, I run it on Windows.

Comment: @Serg I guess from the `d:/feeder.exe`  You can use the MS-DOS prompt by running `CMD`

Comment: @PeterLawrey, I didn't know Windows has `more` command. Anyway, I tried, and it produced no effect. But the issue resolved by `fflush(stdout);`. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If redirected, stdout is probably buffered, meaning that the problem is in the C++ code and not on the Java side. The C++ process will buffer the output and flush several "printf"s at once, as soon as the buffer is full.

If you are able to modify the C++ software, try to do a `fflush(stdout);` after the printf to force the output buffer to be flushed.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely cause is that the `feeder.exe` is not flushing its output stream regularly, and the data is sitting in its output buffer until the buffer fills and is written as a result.

If that is the cause, there is nothing you can do on the Java side to avoid this.  The problem can only be fixed by modifying the `feeder` application.

---

Note that if the data was in the "pipe" that connected the two processes, then reading on the Java side would get it.  Assuming that the end-of-line had been written to the pipe, the `readLine()` call would deliver the line without blocking.